# List all files in dir with color-coding alphabetically (dir and files separated)

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I'm looking for a command to list all files in a directory with `ls` command.

Requirements:
- Alphabetically
- Folders first, then files (both alphabetically)
- No timestamps or other information, just the plain names

I've been experimenting and assembled this command but it's nowhere close to what I need:

```
ls -la | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1| rev
```

I would like an output like this (folders need to have a blue color):

```
folder_A
folder_B
folder_C

file_A  
file_B 
file_C
```

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, that's almost what I need. I've updated my question to make it more clear what I need. So now I need to get rid off all the info like owner, timestamp, ... Because of the grep, the 'd' is colored red. I want all directory names to be colored in blue (or other color).

Comment: Yes that's a good answer as well! Thanks! Works as I wanted! Do you think it possible to add a blank line?

Answer (score 4):

At least with recent versions of `ls`, you can add the option `--group-directories-first` to get a listing with directories above plain files. Your `ls` command is probably already aliased to use `--color=auto` but if not, you can add that (you could use `--color=always`, but that may cause undesirable results if you ever use the command in a pipe). Finally, `-1` causes the output to be presented in a single column. So the full command would be

```
ls -1 --color=auto --group-directories-first
```

Comment: Create an `alias` in `~/.bashrc` to make the entire expression accessible via a short custom command. For example append this line (`alias dir="ls -1 --color=auto --group-directories-first"`) to the end of  `~/.bashrc`; then `source ~/.bashrc` and you will be able to use `dir` instead of the entire expression from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Bruni answered with the `tree` command but removed it? This was actually a good answer, I dug into the man and found the solution: `tree -L 1 --dirsfirst`

This is the output:

```
.
├── docs
├── media
├── node_modules
├── src
├── test
├── API.md
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.rst
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── webpack.config.js
└── yarn.lock

5 directories, 8 files
```

How to get rid of the line '5 dirs, 8 files' without losing the color coding on the folders?

Edit: @steeldriver, thanks for your reply as well: `ls -1 --color=auto --group-directories-first`

Comment: To omit the '5 dirs, 8 files' summary, try adding `--noreport`